# Implementing a search history feature in my Android application

Tags: android

I want every time the user presses on search button, the result has to be saved, because i'm adding 10 latest search history to my app.

In order to make such a feature work, data retrieved should be saved. 
I was searching in the documentation and found this :http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html 
Which class should be used in order to accomplish my work?

Answer (score 0):

To store such kind of data (max 10 items) i would simply store those as JSON in your `SharedPreferences`. See this chapter of the "Storage Options" page of the Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: if i want 20 for example? each row having 8 records? Should I still be using `SharedPreferences`?

Answer (score 0):

use Shared Preferences http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref it better way to compare other option .. store it to JSON String ..

[JSON EXAMPLE](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

How many data you want to be stored in the history? and how long it'll be keeped?
if you only want a few history stored let's say about 5-10 you can use SharedPreferences and encode the data to JSON and if you want to get it you can parse the data. 
for example the history will be like this

```
{
    "history": [
        {
            "text": "aaa",
            "date": "23-03-2013"
        },
        {
            "text": "bbb",
            "date": "22-03-2013"
        },
        {
            "text": "bcccc",
            "date": "22-03-2013"
        }
    ]
}
```

the data will be keeped until your application uninstalled or if you want to clean it you can use SharedPreferences.Editor.clear()

But if you want to store many history data let's say more than 100 data you can used sqlite database  then you can query the data everytime user enter the screen where the search function is located I guess it'll be fast enough because you only getting text not a Blob and if you want to clear it just delete it using query